# run ros terminal commands within a python script

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic, script, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have my ros program ready, and I can control my robot using the terminal commands. Now, I am trying to write a python script to control the robot as I do with the terminal commands. For this purpose, I have been trying several methods explained by others. As expected, I begin with starting the roscore. However, I get error and cannot proceed. Here are what I have done so far:

1- As given [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/215600/how-can-i-run-roscore-from-python/?answer=223264#post-id-223264), I ran the following code

```
import subprocess 
roscore = subprocess.Popen('roscore') 
time.sleep(1)
```

and got this error:

```
>>> runfile('/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/run_roscore.py', wdir='/opt/ros/kinetic/bin')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/run_roscore.py", line 20, in <module>
    roscore = subprocess.Popen('roscore')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

2- Trying the same code with `shell=True` option,

```
roscore = subprocess.Popen('roscore', shell=True)
```

gives the output:

```
runfile('/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/run_roscore.py', wdir='/opt/ros/kinetic/bin')
/bin/sh: 1: roscore: not found
```

3- I also tired other libaries: os and commands

```
import os
os.system('roscore')
```

and

```
import commands
a=commands.getoutput('roscore')
print a
```

to get the same error:

```
runfile('/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/run_roscore.py', wdir='/opt/ros/kinetic/bin')
sh: 1: roscore: not found
```

4- I can run general linux commands with no error. For example the codes below successfully lists the files:

```
os.system('ls -l')
subprocess.Popen('ls -l', shell=True)
a=commands.getoutput('ls -l')
print a
```

Here, `run_roscore.py` is my python file and I placed it in the same directory with `roscore` file.

According to my intuition, it looks like a problem with setup.bash file, but I cannot figure out what the problem is.

I am using ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Nvidia Jetson TX2 developer kit

When giving your answer please, keep in mind that I am not experienced with ROS and Ubuntu environments. So I appreciate if you provide the steps clearly.

Also, please note that starting the roscore is an error I encountered at the beginning of my ultimate goal. At the next steps, I will need to run other commands such as

```
rostopic pub servo std_msgs/UInt16 80
```

and

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0
```

So you may also provide a general recommendation covering my overall goal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297117/run-ros-terminal-commands-within-a-python-script/) by [erjohn](https://answers.ros.org/users/36394/erjohn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going to try and change your whole direction here, because you're trying to use ROS in a very strange way that it was not intended for.

To start your ROS system you should use a [launch file](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch), this will start the roscore automatically. This launch file will also start the serial_node that you need to start. You'll also want to launch the node which controls your robot.

Although you can publish messages using the ROS command line tools, this is not the way it should be done if you're making your own nodes. You should create a publisher as described in [this tutoria](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29)l and publish the messages directly from your script, not via the `rostopic` command line tool.

I can't think of a good reason why you'd ever need to run a ROS command line utility from inside a ROS node.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5